# Extract link from html in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I am trying to extract a link from an HTML body which is coming from a response . Then message looks like this "content":

```
        {
        "rendered": 
         "<div style=
           "padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; 
            position: relative;">
              <iframe style=
                 "position: absolute; 
                  top: 0; 
                  left: 0; 
                  width: 100%; 
                  height: 100%;" 
                  title="Shrewsberry" 
                  src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1000224?h=23334&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479\" 
                  frameborder="0" 
                  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
        </iframe>
        </div>"}
```

I want to get the content inside 'src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1000224?' can anyone help .

This is my code which i use

```
final value = parse(html); // html is the value from response
String parsedString = parse(value.body!.text).documentElement!.text;
print(parsedString);
```

[image: This is the results of what i got]

Comment: There must be some issues with the api, However you can extract URL if that always have this same pattern, in this case find ```.indexOf('src')``` and ```.indexOf('?')``` and extract the URL within those indices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Regex to extract the string from your original string. Given the fact that it looks like HTML I ignored the ** you put in your answer.

In that case the regex `(?<=src=").*?(?=")` should work to retrieve the source. This will work for any source, not just Vimeo.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  String input = "\"content\": { \"rendered\": \"<div style=\"padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; position: relative;\"><iframe style=\"position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;\" title=\"Shrewsberry\" **src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/1000224?\"h=23334&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=58479\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\">\n\"}";
  
  RegExp regex = new RegExp('(?<=src=").*?(?=")');
  var match = regex.firstMatch(input);
  
  if (match == null) {
    print("No match found.");
    return;
  }
  
  print("Result: " + match.group(0)!);
}
```

Output: `Result: https://player.vimeo.com/video/1000224?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple logic if your URL always ends with `?`

```
void main(){ 
String x='"content": { "rendered": "<div style="padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; position: relative;"><iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Shrewsberry" **src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1000224?**h=23334&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">\n"}';
int start= x.indexOf('src');
int end= x.indexOf('?');
print(x.substring(start,end+1));
}
```